# Remove region code from NSLocale.preferredLanguages array

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, macos, localization

After updating my Mac to OSX Sierra, I have noticed, that the `NSLocale.preferredLanguages()` array is now in different format (See quick explanation [here](https://happyteamlabs.com/blog/nslocale-preferredlanguages-changes-in-ios-9/))

Also, same thing happens for IOS9, I suppose.

So, in short, previously we had language format "en", "fr", "ru", e.t.c

Now, we have format "en-US", "en-RU", "fr-US" e.t.c.

In my application, some controls' coordinates were related to the locale. Now, because of the different format, they are all wrong. I was thinking about best way to fix this and to remain support for older versions.

So, my question is:

Is there any way of receiving the language code without region code only? The quick and dirty solution would be to read first two symbols from this string. Is there a more elegant one?

P.S. Can someone please explain Apple's logic to me. I mean, why they have decided, that best option would be to change the existing object format(breaking the backwards compatibility) instead of adding additional field to NSLocale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `substringToIndex` as follows:

```
let str = "en-US"

if let indexOfDash = str.characters.indexOf("-") {
    let langCode = str.substringToIndex(indexOfDash)
}
```

This way should the language code be longer than 2 chars for whatever reason, you don't get caught out.

Comment: Well, yeah, that's the exact way I solved this. I thought, there might be some new field in framework, but it looks like there's none.

Comment: This might be an issue for when there are two dashes like "zh-Hans-HK".

Comment: For scenarios such as these, I recommend using Anbu's answer below. You could then use `array.first` to get the first part.

Answer (score 1):

use

**swift3**

```
let splitArray = "en-US".components(separatedBy: "-") you get // ["en", "US"]
```

**below swift3**

```
let splitArray = "en-US".componentsSeparatedByString("-") // ["en", "US"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSLocale.components(fromLocaleIdentifier:)`

```
let localeID = "zh-Hans-US"
let components = Locale.components(fromIdentifier: localeID)
let languageDesignator = components[NSLocale.Key.languageCode.rawValue]!
print (languageDesignator) // zh
```

Here's an excellent blogpost https://maniak-dobrii.com/preferred-languages-and-ios9/